# Apparently NULL is not known in included files

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I'm facing a strange problem:

I have a main starting with:

```
#include <stdlib.h>     /* this defines NULL */
#include <stdio.h>      /* ditto */
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ctype.h>      /* ditto */
#include <unistd.h>     /* ditto */

#include <linux/input.h>

#include <string.h>     /* ditto */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include "parse.h"
```

... but in the included file:

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)  /* I need this! */

struct parse_key {
    char *name;
    unsigned int value;
} keynames[] = {
    {"KEY_RESERVED", 0},
    {"KEY_ESC", 1},
    {"KEY_1", 2},
    {"KEY_2", 3},
    ...
    {"KEY_MAX", 0x2ff},
    {NULL, 0}
};
```

I need to redefine `NULL`, otherwise I get the error:" error: ‘NULL’ undeclared here (not in a function)".

Note: `NULL`  *is* defined in main file; if I try to `#define` it I get: "warning: "NULL" redefined"

Fix is trivial, but I do not understand what's going on. Can someone shed a light?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to define variables in header files - try fixing that instead.

Comment: `... but in the included file:`...which one?

Comment: You can include `stdlib.h` in another header file also, it need not be a source file only...no issues.

Comment: You do not have at all to (re)define NULL, just use `{0, 0}` without using NULL

Comment: iBug's comment is more or less the answer. Don't declare variables in header files, this is almost always wrong. Once your variables and especially `keynames` isn't declared in a header file but in c .c file, the problem will vanish automatically.

Comment: @bruno that will only mask the actual problem which is declaring a variable in a header file.

Comment: @bruno (and others): I know quite well how to fix the problem. I want to understand what's going on. This is not in line with my seasoned knowledge (I started using C in '81).

Comment: @Jabberwocky: care to explain, please? I know quite well declaring variables or code in a header is bad *style*, but, up to now, there was NOTHING that prevented you from doing it. Before C++/template era it was a common (recommended) practice to `#define` a few variables and then to `#include` code to simulate templates. Real question is: "What changed?"

Comment: @ZioByte ok, I added an answer to try to explain

Comment: @ZioByte please [edit] your question and add a [mcve]

Comment: If I take your code, exactly as shown, assuming that "the included file" is `parse.h`, and compile it, I get "warning: NULL redefined" on the first line of `parse.h`.  If I remove the redefinition, and the ellipsis, I get no errors.  That means the problem is with something you did not show us.  Please do as Jabberwocky asks, and show us code that will demonstrate the problem when we try it for ourselves. It would be helpful if you could also eliminate the use of Linux-specific headers in your test program, but if you can't make that happen, that's useful information in itself.

Comment: "Can someone shed a light?" Somewhere code has `#include "parse.h"` without the prior `#include <stdlib.h>`, else code as posted is edited down too far and is not representative of the problem.  Suggest posting the complete `"parse.h"`.

Answer (score 6):

Do not redefine it.

Just include `<stdlib.h>` in your header files

Also do not define any functions and data in the header files. Just the types declarations, extern variables, function declarations and static inline functions if they are used in many C files.

Answer (score 5):

Usually this issue happens when you don't include the necessary headers in the actual header file, but they get included before the header in certain compilation units.

I.e. you have your header file without the necessary `#include`:

```
// parse.h
#ifndef PARSE_H
#define PARSE_H

struct parse_key
{
    char *name;
    unsigned int value;
}

static inline void key_init(struct parse_key * pk)
{
    pk->name = NULL; // <-- you need it here
}

#endif // PARSE_H
```

And then you have two compilation units, but only one of them includes the appropriate header:

```
// something.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "parse.h"    // <-- preprocessor inserts this when NULL is already known


// something_else.c
#include "parse.h"    // <-- but in this case, it will not compile
```

The only reliable solution is to include all the necessary headers in the problematic header itself.

Since only .c files are compiled, your compiler won't care if you are missing includes in .h files, but IDEs like Visual Studio or Eclipse often show warning messages in these cases.

As a side note, this:

```
struct parse_key {
    char *name;
    unsigned int value;
} keynames[] = {
    {"KEY_RESERVED", 0},
    {"KEY_ESC", 1},
    {"KEY_1", 2},
    {"KEY_2", 3},
    ...
    {"KEY_MAX", 0x2ff},
    {NULL, 0}
};
```

is a variable which will get created in each compilation unit that includes the header file. This means that you will probably also get linker errors telling you that you have duplicate variables.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer, but to try to explain your problem :

if you #include stdlib.h **then** parse.h where NULL is (re)defined you have the redefinition because NULL is already defined in stdlib

if in an **other** file you #include parse.h **but not** stdlib.h you need to define NULL in parse.h else it is not defined

if you really want to use NULL in parse.h you need to #include stdlib inside, but for me the best way is to not use NULL

Answer (score 0):

Macro redefinition is incorrect here. `NULL` is a name reserved by these headers, and defining it before the inclusion of a header that defines it invokes undefined behaviour.

It is preferable to include the *minimal* needed headers in your own headers.

If `NULL` and types like `size_t` are all that you need, do include only **[`<stddef.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19)**.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is defined in the `<stddef.h>` library.